# How to identify if an x86-based Android device can run armeabi-v7a?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Link https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html says that many (but not all) x86-based Android devices can run armeabi-v7a and armeabi NDK binaries. Is there an API to identify if an x86-based device supports armeabi-v7a binaries? Or, is there an adb way to check for this support? Regards.

Answer (score 7):

in case of my x86 android device there is this (accessible from Java side):

```
Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS = {java.lang.String[3]@4180} 
 0 = "x86"
 1 = "armeabi-v7a"
 2 = "armeabi"
```

for adb access to check supported abis, you can try geting props

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist

ro.product.cpu.abilist=x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.product.cpu.abilist32=x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
ro.dalvik.vm.isa.arm=x86
```

more info about checking abis: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/12/16/how-to-identify-the-image-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-user-space

Comment: Also you can obtain properties from native code via `__system_property_read()` (`<sys/system_properties.h>`).

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's a `/system/lib/arm` or something like that if Houdini is available.